# Django RecursionError

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

RecursionError at /cart/ maximum recursion depth exceede It seems to me that the fault lies somewhere in functions

```
def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        # usunięcie koszyka
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True

    @property
    def delivery(self):
        if self.delivery_id:
            return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
        return None

    def get_delivery(self):
        if self.delivery:
            return (self.delivery.cost / Decimal('100')) * self.get_total_price()

    def get_total_price_delivery(self):
        return self.get_total_price() - self.get_delivery()
```

Track

```
Internal Server Error: /cart/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/views.py", line 45, in cart_detail
        'delivery_apply_form': delivery_apply_form})
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
        return template.render(context, request)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 240, in bind_template
        yield
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1044, in render
        output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 711, in resolve
        obj = self.var.resolve(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 852, in resolve
        value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
      File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 915, in _resolve_lookup
        current = current()
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 93, in get_delivery
        if self.delivery:
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 89, in delivery
        return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 89, in delivery
        return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 89, in delivery
        return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 89, in delivery
        return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 89, in delivery
        return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 89, in delivery
        return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line 89, in delivery
        return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
      File "/home/krystian/Project/villain/villain/cart/cart.py", line
```

89, in delivery
            return Delivery.objects.get(id=self.delivery)
          File "/home/krystian/.virtualenvs/vpw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 193, in **get**
            if cls._meta.swapped:
        RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: stack trace .... ?????

Comment: @karthikr my mistake I forgot to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a property named `delivery`. In that method, you query the database, using the value of `self.delivery` - which refers the property you are already in, which therefore calls itself recursively without stopping.

I'm not sure what you are trying to refer to there, but you may have a field and a property which the same name - you should rename one of them.

Comment: I solved the problem already. The error was a function of the delivery.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion is occurring in the urls.py in side the application folder. This usually happens if for example your project name is 'farm' and your app name in the project is 'animal', and you have used the project name in the defining a path for your app.
**Correct Example for defining urls pattern in the project folder** :
Project name: farm
App name : animal

```
urlpatterns = [
path('animal/', include("animal.urls")
]
```

The above means that you have an installed app named animal and when user type after the web address /animal should be taken to the animal app urls module for the routing.

**Wrong Example:
Sample information:** project name = farm, app name = animal

```
urlpatterns = [ path('farm/', include('farm.urls')]
```

The above path is telling django to look inside the farm directorate which is the project folder and is at the time going through the urls.py that is inside the farm folder (which is not an app but a project) thereby going over and over.